# VNC Desktop on AWS

Tags: vnc, remote, aws, amazon

I've installed `ubuntu-desktop` and `tightvncserver` on my `Amazon` `AWS` instance, I've configured `Putty` to forward port`5901` and that all seems to work fine, I can connect but instead of seeing the `Ubuntu` desktop, I only see a solid grey screen with the `X` cursor. I have set my `~/.vnc/xstartup` to execute `gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d` but for some reason this doesn't work, why not I'm wondering...

**EDIT 1**

It is an instance of Ubuntu **14.04**:
`$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-0-0-145 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I double-checked the following:

```
 $gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d

** (gnome-session:11133): WARNING **: Cannot open display:
```

and

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  216 Mar 26 17:37 gnome.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  272 Sep 30  2014 gnome-fallback-compiz.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  310 Sep 30  2014 gnome-fallback.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  213 Mar 26 17:37 ubuntu.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4294 Mar 21  2014 xfce.desktop
```

the complete `xstartup` now looks like:

```
$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
```

**EDIT 2**

Changed `xstartup` to look like:

```
$ cat ~/.vnc/xstartup
#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
#x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
```

killed and restarted the server with 
`$ vncserver -kill :1`
and 
`$ vncserver :1`
but am still getting the same solid background only.

Instead of using `gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback`, I tried `xfce4-ssssssssseion` and that work just fine. I.e. it's some problem with gnome... I also tried to start it manually but got:

```
$ gnome-session --display=:1

(gnome-session-check-accelerated:12077): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

(gnome-session-check-accelerated:12081): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
gnome-session[12065]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session[12065]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? is the ubuntu-2d session actually available? what are the contents of the AWS's /usr/share/xsessions/ directory?

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for your reply, please see **EDIT 1** above.

Comment: So have you tried using `gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback` in your ~/.vnc/xstartup?

Comment: @steeldriver I tried, please see **EDIT 2** above. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not surprised that it errors out when you try to start a session manually: what do you see in the corresponding ~/.vnc session log when you try to start it the "normal" way via a VNC client?